# Getting return list from forEach java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I am trying to use a stream for something and I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding. I am trying to take an array, convert it to a stream, and .forEach item in the array I want to run a function and return a list of the results of that function from the foreach.

Essentially this:

```
Thing[] functionedThings = Array.stream(things).forEach(thing -> functionWithReturn(thing))
```

Is this possible? Am I using the wrong stream function?

Comment: Please, study the [`Stream` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html). It has more methods than just `forEach`.

Comment: @Holger sometimes I look back at questions I wrote and I can't help but facepalm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operation:

```
Thing[] functionedThings = Arrays.stream(things).map(thing -> functionWithReturn(thing)).toArray(Thing[]::new);
```

This method is used to *map* an object to another object; quoting the Javadoc, which says it better:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

Note that the Stream is converted back to an array using the [`toArray(generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method; the generator used is a function (it is actually a method reference here) returning a new Thing array.

Comment: You saved my hours. Thanks. but is there a way without converting it to stream and converting it back to array? isn't it a little inefficient?

Answer (score 7):

You need [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) not forEach

```
List<Thing> functionedThings = Array.stream(things).map(thing -> functionWithReturn(thing)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or `toArray()` on the stream directly if you want an array, like Holger said in the comments.

Comment: There is no `Collectors.toArray()`. Instead, the `Stream` itself offers a `toArray()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to use some setter of `Thing`, so used `peek(...)`

```
List<Thing> functionedThings = Array.stream(things)
    .peek(thing -> thing.setSuccess(true))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```