# Lambda Collect elements created inside an consumer method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm changing from ugly nested for loops to a beautiful designed lambda expressions in java.

Here is my actual code

```
for (String foo : foos) {
    for (Bar bar : bars) {    
        if (bar.getFoo().equals(foo)) {
            FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();                           
            fooBar.setBar(bar);
            listOfFooBar.add(fooBar);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My actual lambda code to replace code above

```
foos.forEach(i -> bars.stream().filter(p -> p.getFoo().equals(i)).findFirst().ifPresent(p -> {
        FooBar s = new FooBar();
        fooBar.setBar(bar);
        listOfFooBar.add(fooBar);
    }));
```

**My question is, there is a way to populate `listOfFooBar` with some kind of collect() method?**

Something like `listOfFooBar = foos.forEach(.....).collect(Collectors.toList());`

**One fact is that bars will always contain every foo, foos is basically a small part of bars.**

If there is a better way (in terms of performance or elegance) to do that lambda, please share.

Comment: I think that it should be `bar.getFoo()` instead of `bar.getBar()`, correct?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yeah, this does make more sense :)

Comment: Why on earth is everyone trying to do everything with `forEach` first? `Stream` has more methods than that.

Comment: @Holger sorry, but that is the purpose of why I wrote "if there is a better way...", i'm still learning java 8 stuffs from the beginning.

Comment: @Holger I believe that switching to a more functional style is hard for most java developers. Most of us have an extremely imperative background, luckily there are sites like SO where we can learn and share.

Comment: "beautiful lambda"? it's a train wreck. I would leave it as your java7 nested loop. the lambda is too long to be readable. just because you *can* do it using a particular tech, doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: @Holger I call this "for-each-itis" and I believe it is or will be a common code smell. I think the reason is that `forEach` is probably the easiest construct to understand for programmers unfamiliar with FP constructs. Since imperative programs have lots of loops, the easiest first step is to transform them into streams with `forEach`. Unfortunately it doesn't easily lead anywhere, and then people get stuck.

Comment: BTW this is not intended as a criticism of the OP. He tried some stuff out, perhaps had a feeling there is a better way, and then came to StackOverflow to ask questions and learn. +1

Comment: @Johnny Willer: it wasn’t meant to be a personal offense, I just commented on an emerged *pattern*, i.e. there was [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32616271/2711488) asked the same day, but, of course, it is not your fault of being not the only one. I’m fully with Stuart Marks here…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is only one Bar per Foo, you could start by creating a map linking Foos to Bars:

```
Map<String, Bar> barsByFoo = bars.stream().collect(toMap(Bar::getFoo, b -> b));
```

If you have a lot more bars than foos, you can filter:

```
Map<String, Bar> barsByFoo = bars.stream()
                                 .filter(b -> foos.contains(b.getFoo()))
                                 .collect(toMap(Bar::getFoo, b -> b));
```

Your nested for loops can then be written:

```
List<FooBar> listOfFooBar = foos.stream()
        .map(barsByFoo::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(FooBar::new)
        .collect(toList());
```

This assumes there is a `FooBar(Bar)` constructor.

Or you could take the problem from the other side and use an (I think) equivalent algo (you would probably benefit from using a `Set<Foo>` in that case):

```
List<FooBar> listOfFooBar = bars.stream()
        .filter(bar -> foos.contains(bar.getFoo()))
        .map(FooBar::new)
        .collect(toList());
```

Either way, it generally helps to step back from your initial loop as a different algo/approach is generally beneficial to a clean lambda solution.

Comment: Yes, there is only one Bar per Foo. I'm testing your code right now

Comment: @JohnnyWiller `Collectors.toMap` or use an `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;`

Comment: Maybe an important fact is that bars will always contains every foo. Actually I want create some instances of FooBar, but I want to create the only that matches the foos. I liked your fourth piece of code, I'm only worried about that `foos.contains`, maybe I can improve that.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller if `foos` is a set of foos it won't be slower than your nested loop - probably faster actually. If it's a list of foos then just use a `Set<String> fooSet = new HashSet<> (foos);` and then `fooSet::contains`. Unless the list of bars is much larger than the list of foos.

Comment: My final approach is your last piece of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go the whole nine yards:

```
List<FooBar> listOfFooBar = foos.stream()
  .flatMap(foo -> bars.stream().filter(bar-> bar.getFoo().equals(foo)).findFirst()
                    .map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()))
  .map(bar -> {
                FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
                fooBar.setBar(bar);
                return fooBar;
              })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you had a `FooBar` constructor that accepts a `Bar` then you could save some lines and write

```
.map(FooBar::new)
```

FWIW in Java 9 you will be able to write

```
.findFirst().stream()
```

Assuming a suitable constructor it would then shorten to

```
List<FooBar> listOfFooBar = foos.stream()
  .flatMap(foo -> bars.stream().filter(bar-> bar.getFoo().equals(foo)).findFirst().stream()))
  .map(FooBar::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**:
Using @Misha's suggestion you can shorten it even more:

```
List<FooBar> listOfFooBar = foos.stream()
  .flatMap(foo -> bars.stream().filter(bar-> bar.getFoo().equals(foo)).limit(1)))
  .map(FooBar::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can replace `.findFirst().map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty())` with `.limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If `FooBar` has a constructor that accepts a `Bar` as an argument:

```
public class FooBar {

    public FooBar(Bar bar) {
        // do something with bar, assign it, etc
    }
}
```

Then, you could do it as follows:

```
List<FooBar> fooBars = foos.stream()
    .map(foo -> bars.stream()
        .filter(bar -> bar.getFoo().equals(foo))
        .findFirst()
        .map(FooBar::new))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This streams your `foos`, and for each `foo`, it streams your `bars` until it finds the first one that matches the current `foo`. If a `foo` is actually found, a new `FooBar` is created from the inner stream's current `bar`. This leaves us with a stream of `Optional<FooBar>`, which is then filtered to only keep the non-empty optionals. Then, the optionals are transformed to the values they contain (which are the `FooBar`s created in the previous step), and finally, these `FooBar`s are collected to a `List<FooBar>`.

*EDIT:* That was my first attempt. Much better to use @zeroflagL's approach:

```
List<FooBar> fooBars = foos.stream()
    .flatMap(foo -> bars.stream()
        .filter(bar -> bar.getFoo().equals(foo))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()))
    .map(FooBar::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```